# Home Office Space using garage conversion room

Tags: drywall, windows

I am using a room that was once a carport that's now a room as an office.  between the converted room and the rest of the house is a (formerly) exterior window plugged/covered with a drywall layer section on the interior and the side in the room is just a window with the bare drywall behind it.  The drywall "plug" on the interior side is obvious with its outline visibly taped with mud and painted to match the wall.  How can I remove the window plug with the least amount of work/damage? would I just cut the taped outline and pry it out and add some kind of frame for its wall-space? I want to restore the window and use it as a wall-opening between the two rooms, as the air pressure from the HVAC in the converted room needs to be vented back to the rest of the house return flow...?

[image: INTERIOR WALL WINDOW COVER][image: Vie of same window from converted room]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add some pictures of the interior ex-window? What do you mean by the "?" at the end? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: My apologies for violating any protocol...

Answer (score 1):

A picture of the interior as it is now -- and an example from the Internet of what you want it to look like when you're finished -- would be really helpful.  Without that it's hard to suggest all the steps you need to do.

However, to remove the drywall, cut the tape with a utility knife.

It sounds like you need to replace the interior trim.  That's a detailed project for a beginner.  You may want to hire a trim carpenter to help you.